# Auto deselect the "first selected item" after selecting two items in Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to web dev and I cannot figure out how to do this task. Here is the problem statement.

Given three checkboxes If select box1 and then box2 it should show marked. Now if I select box3 then box1 should be automatically unchecked and must reflect in UI.

Here is the code sample I'm trying.

```
export default function CheckboxesGroup() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    gilad: true,
    jason: false,
    antoine: false,
  });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  const { gilad, jason, antoine } = state;
  const error = [gilad, jason, antoine].filter((v) => v).length !== 2;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControl required error={error} component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
        <FormLabel component="legend">Pick two</FormLabel>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox checked={gilad} onChange={handleChange} name="gilad" />}
            label="Gilad Gray"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox checked={jason} onChange={handleChange} name="jason" />}
            label="Jason Killian"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox checked={antoine} onChange={handleChange} name="antoine" />}
            label="Antoine Llorca"
          />
        </FormGroup>
        <FormHelperText>You can display an error</FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

or you can goto  https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/checkboxes/CheckboxesGroup.js

Here is the output: https://y9q9rx--run.stackblitz.io

Comment: Hello, welcome to this site! You have the option to create executable code samples, including HTML and Javascript. That would make it much easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you have only 3 options then you can set particular conditions for checked items
By changing the handleChange function like this

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {name, checked} = event.target;
    let newState = {};
    if([gilad, jason, antoine].filter((v) => v).length === 2 && checked === true){
        if(name === 'gilad'){
            newState = {jason: false};
        } else if(name === 'jason'){
            newState = {gilad: false};
        } else if(name === 'antoine'){
            newState = {gilad: false};
        }
    }
    setState({ ...state,...newState, [name]: checked });
};
```

Comment: I asking in general there could be more than three options. In actual project the data is being received from the database so I do not know the size of the data in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, if I misunderstood the question, please tell me. As far as I understand, you're trying to enforce the user to select at most 2 boxes, further selection will cancel the earliest selection.

For this problem, we can get an insight that the order of selection matters, but the data structure you are using does not reflect this. You are now using

```
{
  gilad: true,
  jason: false,
  antoine: false,
}
```

as the state, which does not contains the information of the order of checking. In this case, I would suggest using an array instead, which can keep track of the ordering information more easily.

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(['gilad']);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, checked } = event.target;

  // handles unchecking the checked box
  if (!checked) {
    setState(prev => prev.filter(n => n !== name));
  } else {
    const stateWithNewName = [...state, name];

    // only take the latest two names
    setState(stateWithNewName.slice(-2));
  }
};

const error = state.length !== 2;
```

for the `Checkbox` component,

```
// notice the modification for the `checked` prop
<Checkbox checked={state.includes('gilad')} onChange={handleChange} name="gilad" />
```